# "Prelude.read: no parse" when working with list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, integer, boolean, head

I'm very new to Haskell and struggling to see my mistake here:

```
same :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
same n xs = if head xs == n
                then True
                else False

function :: [Integer] -> Bool
function (n:xs) = same n xs

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= putStrLn . show . function . (map read)
```

It compiles just fine but when I run it with

```
10 [7, 3, 5, 4, 4]
```

for example as arguments, I get

```
Prelude.read: no parse
```

I also tried it without the integer-list, where it worked just fine.

Comment: That can't compile: it defines `function` twice.

Comment: right, my bad, fixed

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running the program from the CLI as `program 10 [7, 3, 5, 4, 4]`.

In such case, `getArgs` returns the list `["10", "[7,", "3,", "5,", "4,",  "4]"]`.

Trying to parse each string in the list as an integer simply fails because of the additional characters.

You should choose a better way to pass arguments. I'd suggest either `program 10 7 3 5 4 4` or `program 10 "[7, 3, 5, 4, 4]"`. The first passes many arguments, the second only two (the second being a string with the whole list). Whatever you choose, you should adapt your code accordingly.

Here's an example.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
   [strN, strNs] <- getArgs
   let n = read strN
       ns = read strNs
   putStrLn $ "Numeric arg: " ++ show n
   putStrLn $ "List arg, incremented: " ++ show (map succ ns)
```

Invoking this as `program 10 "[1, 4, 7]"` from the CLI should work.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. 
When I remove the brackets and the commas it works just fine.
The problem is just, that we're only supposed to change the same-function. How could I work on a list, given in this syntax?

Comment: If you can't change `main`, the input must be without extra characters. Double check your exercise text. Maybe the example `10 [1, ...]` is not meant to be a program invocation from the CLI, but an input to `function`, directly, e.g. by calling it from GHCi. (And, BTW, I'd suggest to check your program on lists of length 0, 1, 2, 3 to see if it works properly.)

Comment: I think you're right. In the examples they just input the arguments to the same-function directly. How can I do that in the CLI?

Comment: @dYTe You can't from the CLI in a direct way. Instead, from there, run `ghci YourFile.hs` and then you'll get a prompt from which you can evaluate `function args`.

Comment: Thank You very much, you helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also do as follows;

```
firstEqualSecond :: [Int] -> Bool
firstEqualSecond (f:s:_) = f == s

pgm :: IO ()
pgm = getArgs >>= \(a:b:_) -> (putStrLn.show.firstEqualSecond) (read a:read b)
```